# convert rows into columns, eliminate columns and arrange sites by date in R

Tags: r

My data frame **"df"** is the following

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
           Column1 = c("Station Name:","Date",
                       "01/01/2000","02/01/2000","07/03/2010","31/12/2020",
                       "Station Name:","Date","01/01/2000","02/01/2000",
                       "07/03/2010","31/12/2020","Station Name:","Date","01/01/1999",
                       "02/01/1999","01/10/2009","31/12/2020"),
           Column2 = c("A","Time","00:00:00",
                       "00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","B","Time","00:00:00",
                       "00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00","C","Time","00:00:00",
                       "00:00:00","00:00:00","00:00:00"),
           Column3 = c("NA","Value","2.9","2.42",
                       "2.06","1.92","NA","Value","1.19","1.16","1.13",
                       "1.08","NA","Value","12.5","8.39","6.48","9.87"))
```

[image: DF]

I must eliminate the **Time** column and arrange the **Value** of each **Station (A,B,C)** to look like the following table:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fill()` from `tidyverse` package

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Station = ifelse(Column1 == "Station Name:", Column2, NA)) %>%
  fill(Station) %>% filter(!(Column1 == "Station Name:" | Column1 == "Date")) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = Column3, names_from = Station)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  Column1    Column2  A     B     C    
  <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 01/01/2000 00:00:00 2.9   1.19  NA   
2 02/01/2000 00:00:00 2.42  1.16  NA   
3 07/03/2010 00:00:00 2.06  1.13  NA   
4 31/12/2020 00:00:00 1.92  1.08  9.87 
5 01/01/1999 00:00:00 NA    NA    12.5 
6 02/01/1999 00:00:00 NA    NA    8.39 
7 01/10/2009 00:00:00 NA    NA    6.48
```

Adding `values_fn` argument will convert all values to numeric simultaneously

```
df %>% mutate(Station = ifelse(Column1 == "Station Name:", Column2, NA)) %>%
  fill(Station) %>% filter(!(Column1 == "Station Name:" | Column1 == "Date")) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = Column3, names_from = Station, values_fn = as.numeric)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  Column1    Column2      A     B     C
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 01/01/2000 00:00:00  2.9   1.19 NA   
2 02/01/2000 00:00:00  2.42  1.16 NA   
3 07/03/2010 00:00:00  2.06  1.13 NA   
4 31/12/2020 00:00:00  1.92  1.08  9.87
5 01/01/1999 00:00:00 NA    NA    12.5 
6 02/01/1999 00:00:00 NA    NA     8.39
7 01/10/2009 00:00:00 NA    NA     6.48
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is how to deal with this situation generally, for a messed-up data set - probably created in a spreadsheet. This should work even if more station data is included.

First, get the station names:

```
stations <- unique(df$Column2[which(df$Column1 == "Station Name:")])
```

Where do the station markers start and stop?

```
start_station <- which(df$Column1 == "Station Name:")

end_station <- 
  c((which(df$Column1 == "Station Name:") - 1) [2:
      length(which(df$Column1 == "Station Name:"))], 
      length(df$Column1))
```

Put the station marker at each appropriate row:

```
df$Station <- rep(stations, 
                  times = end_station - start_station + 1)
```

remove spreadsheet header lines

```
df2 <- df[-c(start_station, start_station + 1), c(1, 3, 4)]
```

The data set is now tidy, but we need it to be wider

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Station, 
                           values_from = Column3)
```

Finishing touch, rename the first column:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- rename(df2, Date = Column1)
> df2
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  Date       A     B     C    
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 01/01/2000 2.9   1.19  NA   
2 02/01/2000 2.42  1.16  NA   
3 07/03/2010 2.06  1.13  NA   
4 31/12/2020 1.92  1.08  9.87 
5 01/01/1999 NA    NA    12.5 
6 02/01/1999 NA    NA    8.39 
7 01/10/2009 NA    NA    6.48
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


clean_data <- df %>%
  setNames(c("date", "station", "value")) %>%
  mutate(station = case_when(
    station == "Time" ~ lag(station),
    station == "00:00:00" ~ NA_character_,
    TRUE ~ station
  )) %>%
  fill(station) %>%
  filter(str_detect(date, "^\\d*\\/")) %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date),
         value = as.numeric(value))
clean_data
#>          date station value
#> 1  2000-01-01       A  2.90
#> 2  2000-01-02       A  2.42
#> 3  2010-03-07       A  2.06
#> 4  2020-12-31       A  1.92
#> 5  2000-01-01       B  1.19
#> 6  2000-01-02       B  1.16
#> 7  2010-03-07       B  1.13
#> 8  2020-12-31       B  1.08
#> 9  1999-01-01       C 12.50
#> 10 1999-01-02       C  8.39
#> 11 2009-10-01       C  6.48
#> 12 2020-12-31       C  9.87

clean_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = station, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   date           A     B     C
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2000-01-01  2.9   1.19 NA   
#> 2 2000-01-02  2.42  1.16 NA   
#> 3 2010-03-07  2.06  1.13 NA   
#> 4 2020-12-31  1.92  1.08  9.87
#> 5 1999-01-01 NA    NA    12.5 
#> 6 1999-01-02 NA    NA     8.39
#> 7 2009-10-01 NA    NA     6.48
```